# Why Tuple0-22 and Function0-22 instead of a HList

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Is there a reason (performance, memory, typesystem) why a Tuple is not a HList and Function is not a mapping form a HList to some value?

Comment: My (uninformed) guess: originally (when the tuple and function types were introduced) the typesystem was not powerful enough to build a HList; and now it's probably muuuuuch too late to change or everything would break really badly; personally, I'd really love the change though. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Performance and memory both.  Tuples have `O(1)` access for their elements; as typically constructed, `HList` is a list, and thus has `O(n)`.  Also, tuples require memory for one extra object with `n` references to other objects, while `HList` (as a list) requires one object each (plus a `next` pointer).  Since the overhead of an object is about two references, this turns `n+2` memory usage into `4n+2`.  Not so awesome for a core language construct.

Answer (score 2):

An [HArray](http://jnordenberg.blogspot.de/2009/09/type-lists-and-heterogeneously-typed.html) which extends AnyVal will probably have comparable performance and memory requirements as the TupleX classes. The only overhead will be the length of the array and the array index bounds checking.

Comment: That might have been sort of true before `Tuple` was specialized, if the type system was modified to allow variable length type lists.

Comment: Good point about specialization. Not sure what you mean with "variable length type lists". You don't mean TList I suppose (which certainly is variable length)?

Comment: Well, I just mean that it needs significant reworking.  Right now you have to manually specify the types and number of arguments for the `HArray.apply` methods.

Comment: If I would had been aware that HArray exists, I would have replace HList through HArray in my questions. +1 for mentioning it.